# Merging SPF records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, spf, txt-record

I have one SPF record:

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:111.111.111.111 -all
```

and I need to add one more:

```
v=spf1 ip4:222.222.222.222 include:_spf.example.net ~all
```

How to merge them correctly? Is

```
v=spf1 ip4:222.222.222.222 include:_spf.example.net a mx ip4:111.111.111.111 ~all
```

ok?

Comment: Save that it needs a `-all` at the end, it looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it, but I believe the formatting has to be:

`v=spf1 a mx ip4:111.111.111.111 ip4:222.222.222.222 include:_spf.example.net ~all`

With the "a" and "mx" at the beginning.

Edit: `~all` is fine to use, but it's recommended to use `-all` for SPF to work more effectively.

Comment: From a security perspective, I'd recommend using a HardFail only, as well as looking into DMARC and DKIM.

Comment: I've always used -all in my SPFs, and reading on OpenSPF website explains why it's best to use this over ~all. So thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. However, note that the mechanisms are evaluated in order<sup>[1]</sup>. Therefore, if `_spf.example.net` were to include `Fail` mechanisms, they'd trigger before `a mx ip4:111.111.111.111`. If that's not what you want, leave the includes at the end, just before the ~all.

---

[1] http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax

Comment: That is explicitly **not** how `include:` works, as the very page you link to makes clear: "*evaluating a `-all` directive in the referenced record does not terminate the overall processing and does not necessarily result in an overall Fail. Better names for this mechanism would have been "if-pass"...*".